# Are there IEEE 754 floating point values x whose inverted values 1/x are also exact floating point values, other than 2^n?

Tags: math, floating-point, ieee-754

All powers of 2, e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, etc., have inverse values (1 again, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, etc.) that can be expressed exactly as IEEE 754 floating point values.

But I can't think of any other value that meets this condition.
For example, the inverse value of 2.5 is 0.4, which is stored in 32 bit as 0.4000000059604644775390625.

Are there other values except the powers of 2 that have inverse values with exact representations in IEEE 754?

**EDIT**
Based on the first answer, which is not what I am looking for, I want to clarify:
The value, which is > 1, and the inverse value, which is < 1, should BOTH have exact floating point representations.
The integer multiples of the inverse powers of 2,
e.g. 3 * 0.125 = 0.375,
indeed have exact floating point representations, but *their* inverse values,
e.g. 1 / 0.375 = 1 / (3 * 1/8) = 8 / 3 = 2.666...,
don't, except if the integer multiple itself is a power of 2.

Comment: Why do you think that if `x` is exact, `1/x` (or `x^-1`) should be exact too? It's only about 'exponent' part - the power of 2, which can be positive (2,4,8...) or negative (0.5, 0.25, 0.125...) - but not the whole number! While both 3 * 8 and 3 * 1/8 are exact, both 1 / (3 * 8) and 1 / (3 * 1/8) are not.

Comment: What about `-1`?

Comment: IEEE-754 includes decimal floating-point. Do you want to ask for only binary floating-point?

Comment: @raina77ow: x and 1/x should both be exact because I was looking for. I wanted to know if there is any x at all that satifies this condition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I didn't know that, so I asked for base-2 only. Also, from your comment to the answer below, I accept that there is 0 and inf., but I was neither looking for these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there IEEE 754 floating point values x whose inverted values 1/x are also exact floating point values, other than 2^n?

Yes, as -1 is a simple example. [@chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64401669/are-there-ieee-754-floating-point-values-x-whose-inverted-values-1-x-are-also-ex/64402758#comment113880667_64401669)

For *positive* numbers: no, not for base 2 floating point encodings<sup>1</sup>.

Each common finite floating point number is a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), some `integer_n/power_of_2`.   An exact inverse is `power_of_2/integer_n`.  For that inverse to be exactly representable, `integer_n` must also be a power of 2.

---

<sup>1</sup>  Recent versions of IEEE 754 also specify base-10 encoding.

Comment: 0 and ∞ are floating-point values *x* whose inverted values 1 / *x* are also exact floating-point values. Also maybe NaN, depending on the meaning of “value.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil True that 0, ∞, NaN deserve special consideration.

Comment: _For positive numbers: no, not for base 2 floating point encodings_ Thank you, that's what I wanted to know. About base-10: Interesting! When was this introduced? But the `double` precision floating point data type in all programming languages I know is base-2, so that's not relevant for me.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Re: base 10.  C supports FP using base 10, 2, 16, 4, 8, 32, .....  Non base 2 implementation have all died out from my awareness 15 years ago,  Early C had to contend and support with early innovated times.  Next C (C2X) may support decimal FP as a new type.  Avoid assuming C is static.

Answer (score 1):

*What follows is apparently* applicable to binary representations only.*

All the inverse powers of 2 multiplied by integers (limited by mantissa bits available in specific representation - 23 for binary32, 52 for binary64 etc.) are exactly represented in IEEE754, too.

For example, this:

```js
for (let i = 0.9375; 
  i !== 0; /* never try this at home kids */ 
  i -= 0.0625) 
{
  console.log(i.toFixed(20));
}
```

... while seemingly dangerous, actually works fine as all those numbers are exact representations.

It's important to remember though, that exponent in binaryXX formats represents power of 2, not of 10 (or any other number for that matter). So while 0.5 is exact, 0.05 (and most of its multiplications) is not.

The same goes about inversing a number (for x, getting 1/x). Essentially it boils down to:

```
x = m * 2^e
1/x = 1/(m * 2^e) => (1/m) * (1/2^e) => (1/m) * 2^-e
```

Inversing exponent part of IEEE-754 representation is just reversing its sign (as 1/2^x = 2^-x). But inversing mantissa part (in the given format) is not possible.

---

Overall, that still leaves us with a really small subset of floating points. In layman's terms, 'to end with 5' is necessary, but not sufficient.

*(lesson learnt: never assume the OP's intent is obvious even if it's obvious to you)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I asked for. I will clarify my question.